# Installing Oracle 11g on Windows SBS 2011 64 bit

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

In the Oracle web site, I found the following requirements:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/install.111/b32006/reqs.htm#CHDHGGFE

```
Oracle Database for x64 Windows is supported on the following operating systems:
    Windows Server 2003 - all x64 editions
    Windows Server 2003 R2 - all x64 editions
    Windows XP Professional x64 Edition
    Windows Vista x64 - Business, Enterprise, and Ultimate editions
```

Is it possible to install an Oracle 11g on windows SBS2011 64 bit? 
Thanks
Alberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Oracle support document 1307195.1, Oracle's stance is:

> Microsoft Windows Small Business Server
>
> Windows Small Business Server is a product suite that bundles several
>   Microsoft products, including the Windows operating system. Oracle
>   Database does not certify with product suites, only operating systems
>   and platforms. To distinguish whether Oracle Database certifies with a
>   particular Windows Small Business Server version, find that suite's
>   operating system version and consult My Oracle Support's certification
>   matrix using that operating system version.

Small Business Server 2011 is based on Windows Server 2008 R2. According to the certification matrix at Oracle support, the following versions of Oracle are certified for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64:

- 10.2.0.5.0
- 11.2.0.1.0
- 11.2.0.2.0
- 11.2.0.3.0
- 11.2.0.4.0
- 12.2.0.1.0